# List of filtered Events is breaking paging?

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, paged

I have a list of events that are displaying in date order, with events in the past being hidden.

The issue is that in total, there are 3 pages of events, but once the past events are hidden, there are only enough events to fill 2 pages. However, a third, blank page is still present and can be accessed through the paging links.

This is the code on my events list page:

```
<?php $today = date("Ymd");?>

<?php $paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
query_posts( '&post_type=upcomingevents&paged=' . $paged );?> 

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'upcomingevents', 'paged'=> $paged, 'meta_key' => 'start_date', 'meta_compare' => '>=', 'meta_value' => $today, 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC' )); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts('post_type=upcomingevents') ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

And this is the paging code in my functions file:

```
function paginate() {
global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
$pagination = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => true,
    'type' => 'plain'
);
if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );
if ( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );
echo paginate_links( $pagination );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have two queries that look to me to be competing.

1. You are using `query_posts` to alter the main query but are not including any of your filters in that one.
2. You are creating a new query with your filters-- `'meta_key' => 'start_date'`, etc-- and looping over that query result set to show your posts.
3. Then to paginate you using the main query-- `$wp_query`-- which doesn't have any of your filtering. It isn't surprising that things are out of sync.

You need to re-factor this to only use one query and not jumble the two together. I believe you can use the `$loop` object just as you are using `$wp_query` in the pagination function.

```
function paginate($loop) {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $loop->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $loop->query_vars['paged'] :   $current = 1;
  $pagination = array(
    'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $loop->max_num_pages,
    'current' => $current,
    'show_all' => true,
    'type' => 'plain'
  );
  // ...
```

I can't promise that that is a complete solution. What you have got is complicated and difficult to test without duplicating your database and page structure.

It is also possible that you could use a `pre_get_posts` filter to alter the main query and save the database some pain.

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for your response.
I tried those changes in the functions file you suggested, but the paging just disappeared all together.

The query code I have copied and pasted from multiple places (as you can probably tell) to get it to do everything I need to do.

Is there a way I can put all of my code into a single query that anyone can suggest - I'm not a developer so I can't write this stuff myself.

Thank you!

Comment: hmmm... I've used `paginate_links` very similarly. `var_dump($pagination);` for me. Edit the question please.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - What do i need to edit in the question?

Comment: I want to know what your `$pagination` array looks like. So, add `var_dump($pagination);` after you create that array and paste the output into the question.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. thanks for explaining!

This is what printed:
`array(6) { ["base"]=> string(40) "http://wordpresstesting/events/page/%#%/" ["format"]=> string(0) "" ["total"]=> float(3) ["current"]=> int(1) ["show_all"]=> bool(true) ["type"]=> string(5) "plain" }`